# error when trying to post json to server Code=3840

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode

am posting to server some data as json and getting json response from it .. like this:

```
             let decoded4  = userDefaults.object(forKey: "nationalities") as! Data
        let decodedNationalities = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decoded4) as! [Nationality]
        for nationality in decodedNationalities {
            if nationality.name == self.nationality {
                idnationality = nationality.id
            }

        }
        if conttype == "Single visit"{
            conttype = "single_visit"
        }else {
            conttype = "multi_visit"
        }
        print(days)
        if days.hasPrefix(","){
            days.remove(at: days.startIndex)
        }
        if days.hasSuffix(","){
            days.remove(at: days.endIndex)
        }
        let todosEndpoint: String = "my link"
        guard let todosURL = URL(string: todosEndpoint) else {
            print("Error: cannot create URL")
            return
        }
        var todosUrlRequest = URLRequest(url: todosURL)
        todosUrlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
        todosUrlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        let newTodo: [String: Any] = ["email": UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "CustomerEmail")!, "password": UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "CustomerPassword")!, "id_address": addid, "quantity_staff": maidn, "id_service": idservice, "id_region": idregion, "id_city": idcity, "id_nationality": idnationality, "start_date": "2018-05-09",  "contract_type": "single_visit", "shift_type": "day", "weekdays": days, "starttime": starttime, "endtime": endtime]
        print(newTodo)
        let jsonTodo: Data
        do {
            jsonTodo = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: newTodo, options: [])
            todosUrlRequest.httpBody = jsonTodo
        } catch {
            print("Error: cannot create JSON from todo")
            return
        }

        let session = URLSession.shared

        let task = session.dataTask(with: todosUrlRequest) {
            (data, response, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                print("error calling POST on /public/api/register_customer")
                print(error!)
                return
            }
            guard let responseData = data else {
                print("Error: did not receive data")
                return
            }

            // parse the result as JSON, since that's what the API provides
            do {
                guard let receivedTodo = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData,options: []) as? [String: Any] else {
                    print("Could not get JSON from responseData as dictionary")
                    return
                }
                print("The todo is: " + receivedTodo.description)

                guard let status = receivedTodo["success"] as? Int else {
                    print("Could not get status from JSON")
                    return
                }

                if status == 0{
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueerr", sender: self)
                    }

                    print("The status is: 0")
                    guard let messages = receivedTodo["message"] as? String else {
                        print("Could not get messages from JSON")
                        return
                    }
                    print(messages)


                }
                else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "successsegue", sender: self)
                    }
                    print("Success!")
                }
            } catch  {
                print(error)
                return
            }
        }
        task.resume()


    }
```

when i run it .. it posted the correct values which are:

> ["email": "lamatat@gmail.com", "id_service": 3, "id_region": 1,
>   "id_city": 3, "id_address": 22, "weekdays": "tue", "contract_type":
>   "single_visit", "id_nationality": 4, "password":
>   "4169faf51ce3c5fb8850451b441a363906f16d69", "endtime": 12,
>   "starttime": 8, "shift_type": "day", "quantity_staff": 1,
>   "start_date": "2018-05-09"]

i got error as response which is:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.}

when am sure 100% of the values and tried the excat same one in postman and got this as result:

```
   {
"success": true,
"message": "Adding new Order was successful.",
"id_order": 210,
"shift": {
    "id": 31,
    "id_region": 1,
    "id_city": 3,
    "id_nationality": 4,
    "id_service": 3,
    "shift_date": "2018-05-09 00:00:00",
    "shift_type": "day",
    "weekday": "tue",
    "quantity_staff": 64,
    "lead_hours": 10,
    "created_at": "2018-05-07 12:54:48",
    "updated_at": "2018-05-09 10:47:37",
    "deleted_at": null,
    "price_per_visit": 50
}
}
```

why would i got this error from the app?!

someone please help! i have no clue whats wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Just try this instead for your one. Change this to

```
jsonTodo = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: newTodo, options: [])
```

**to**

```
let jsonTodo = JSONStringify(value: newTodo as AnyObject)
```

Add This method inside your controller

```
func JSONStringify(value: AnyObject,prettyPrinted:Bool = false) -> String{

    let options = prettyPrinted ? JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted : JSONSerialization.WritingOptions(rawValue: 0)

    if JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(value) {

        do{
            let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: value, options: options)
            if let string = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) {
                return string as String
            }
        }catch {

            print("error")
            //Access error here
        }

    }
    return ""

}
```

*But if you still facing same issue. Change your httoBody also like this

```
request.httpBody = jsonTodo.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

Comment: got this Use of unresolved identifier 'JSONStringify'

Comment: can you show me hoe to actually replace it in my code please?

Comment: still getting this: Use of unresolved identifier 'JSONStringify'

Comment: @lamatat sry! i forgot to add method. let me know

Comment: i got the same error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.}